# Оптимизация нейронных сеток под GPU, что будет узким местом?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

Обучаю нейронную сетку, типа трансформер сделанную на Python, пока на CPU i5 12gen. У этого процессора 16 потоков, и по монитору видно, что они все суммарно загружаются на ~60%. Вопрос, будет ли, и существенно ли, увеличение скорости при использовании графической карты например RTX 4090 или даже нескольких?

У меня сомнения возникают, поскольку я вижу, что на CPU он не может использовать все ресурсы и возможно что-то является узким местом кроме как мультиядерности. Процесс существенно простой, кроме расчета сетки практически ничего нет.

От величины сетки процент загрузки практически не меняется. Сейчас пробую сетку на ~200млн параметров. Памяти пока хватает, потребляет максимум 30-40гб из 64гб в моменты отправки пачки на обучение.

Вот так выглядит код класса сетки, учится через MSELoss && Adam. Про загрузку в 60% речь идет когда выполняет код сетки. В данном случае около 50млн. параметров. На мой взгляд начинающего сеточника, здесь кажется особо оптимизировать нечего:

```
class TransformerModel(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, in_vocab_size, sz_in, sz_out = 1):
        super(TransformerModel, self).__init__()

        emb_sz = 512
        n_heads = 16
        c_layers = 32
        c_feedForward = 512
        dropout = 0.0

        self.d_model = emb_sz
        self.sz_in = sz_in
        self.sz_out = sz_out

        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(
            num_embeddings=in_vocab_size,
            embedding_dim=emb_sz)

        self.pos_encoder = PositionalEncoding(
            d_model=emb_sz,
            dropout=dropout)

        self.transformer_layer = nn.TransformerEncoderLayer(
            d_model=emb_sz,
            nhead=n_heads,
            dim_feedforward=c_feedForward,
            dropout=dropout)

        self.transformer = nn.TransformerEncoder(
            self.transformer_layer,
            num_layers=c_layers)

        self.fc_pack_seq_len = nn.Linear(sz_in, 1)
        self.gelu = nn.GELU()
        self.fc_pack_emb = nn.Linear(emb_sz, sz_out)

    def forward(self, x):
        assert x.size(1) == self.sz_in
        x = self.embedding(x) * math.sqrt(self.d_model)
        x = self.pos_encoder(x)
        out = self.transformer(x)
        out = self.fc_pack_seq_len(out.transpose(1,2))[:,:,0]
        out = self.gelu(out)
        out = self.fc_pack_emb(out)
        if self.sz_out > 1:
            return out
        return out[:,0]
```

Comment: `GPU` в принципе считает нейросетки на порядок быстрее, чем `CPU`. И параллелить вычисления на `CPU` задача не такая простая, загрузить все потоки на 100% удаётся крайне редко, так что это не показатель. Другое дело, что надо смотреть, сколько памяти именно на видеокарте нужно будет этой сетке, главное чтобы туда ещё не упёрлось. А так обычно на `GPU` ускорение расчёта нейросеток есть всегда, поэтому видеокарты и используют так активно.

Comment: Т.е. весь расчет должен помещаться в память одной видеокарты? Т.е. пачки нужно будет делать поменьше?

Comment: А если будет две-три видеокарты, оно в два-три раза будет быстрее? Или будут какие-нибудь существенные расходы на распределение расчетов между картами?

Comment: Ну, я не большой специалист в этом деле, но кажется да, нужно будет как-то подстраиваться под размер памяти видеокарты. И с распараллеливанием на видеокарты примерно те же проблемы, что с распараллеливанием на потоки процессора - это не так просто, если вообще возможно, точно не помню. Одна мощная карта с большой памятью лучше. Но, повторюсь, я не спец.

Comment: Интересно, за что вопрос минусуют. За отсутствие кода?

Comment: Код добавил. Как я и упоминал, это просто сетка на питоне.

Comment: Ну, это только предположение было с моей стороны. Я минус не ставил, наоборот компенсировал чей-то минус.

Answer (score 1):

В результате, проверка на практике показала, что с использованием GeForce RTX 4090 сетки на питоне считаются в 40-50 раз быстрее чем на голом процессоре i5 12600. При этом, при расчетах на видяхе, процессоры видяхи загружались на 95 и выше процентов.